# Split 2 form and make it live

Tags: vb.net

I'm kinda a "not-so-good-programmer" so please keep the answers understandable.

So, i have 2 form :

form 1 on displayA (inside form 1 is 25% is form1 itself, and 75% is form 2 for live preview), i using panel1 for "75% form2".

form 2 on displayB

this is an illustration :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ireh.jpg

when i clicking button1 on form1 it  succees showing form2 (on DisplayB). this is a script:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form2.Location = Screen.AllScreens(UBound(Screen.AllScreens)).Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)

    Form2.Show()

End Sub
```

And this a script which i use to show 75% form2 (on DisplayA):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim frm As New Form2()
    frm.TopLevel = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(frm)
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

the situation now is :

1. i succeed make form2 show on DisplayB, by clicking button1 on form1.
2. i succeed make 75% form2 show on form1 (DisplayA), But it stuck at "New form2"

[exsample: if i make an update label1.text on form2 (DisplayB), the 75% form2 (DisplayA) is not changed.]

So, i need help to:

1. make form2 (on DisplayB) live with form2 (on DisplayA).
2. if i have wrong script, please tell me.

Im sorry for very bad English, Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does it throw a exception at `New Form2()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SplitContainer control instead of your own Panels.

The SplitContainer control provides two interior panels.  In order to *hide* one of the panels, you would simply collapse it:

```
SplitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = True
```

To add your form to the panel, it would be like this:

```
Dim frm As New Form2()
frm.TopLevel = False
frm.Visible = True
SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm)
```

Comment: yeah, its make "real form2" shown at panel2. But Panel2 not sync When i change text "label1.text" on "real form2".

Comment: @user3630649 You do know I can't see your code, right?  I don't know how you are referencing this "label".  When are you trying to update this label?  What event?